# Initial focus for jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am opening a jquery dialog box from a link in the HTML page. When the content of the dialog box is longer than the specified height of the box, the initial focus is at the bottom of the dialog box. (the specified height is not changeable -- this is used in a number of different places.) 
How do I get the focus to be at the top of the dialog box when it first opens?

JQuery dialog box code in head of HTML:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#dialog-detail").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 700,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            }
        });

        $("#create-detail")
            .click(function () {
                $("#dialog-detail").dialog("open");
                $("#dialog-detail").focus("div");
            });
    });
</script>
```

A truncated version of the dialog box HTML code:

```
<div id="dialog-detail" title="Balance Entry Report Detail">
    <div id='extPageContainer'>
        <header>
            <h3>Account information</h3>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <input type='submit'  value="Close window" onclick="window.close();"  />
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link to open the dialog box is in a table listing transaction information -- the dialog box is detail information on one of the entries in the table:

```
<a id="create-detail" style="cursor: pointer;">231435353</a>
```

Comment: `$("#dialog-detail").focus("div")` doesn't make sense. When you call `.focus()` with an argument, you're binding an event handler, so the argument has to be a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `.focus()` correctly. When called with an argument, the argument is supposed to be a handler function that gets called when the specified element receives focus. A string as the argument is not valid.

If you want to set focus to a specific element, you should call `.focus()` with no arguments on the element. If you want focus to be on the `<header>` element, you can do:

```
    $("#create-detail")
        .click(function () {
            $("#dialog-detail").dialog("open");
            $("#dialog-detail header").focus();
        });
```